# Java Pattern for data within Double or single quotes excluding quotes inside a parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need a Java Pattern to fetch all the attributes of an HTML element which would be passed as String.
Initially, I had Used to split them using the following Pattern

```
private static Pattern scriptletvalue1 = Pattern.compile("value=\"([^\"]*)\"");
private static Pattern scriptletvalue2 = Pattern.compile("value='([^']*)'");
private static Pattern scriptletId1 = Pattern.compile("id=\"([^\"]*)\"");
private static Pattern scriptletId2 = Pattern.compile("id='([^\']*)'");
```

and so on for all the attributes, This would work fine until there are no double quotes inside the attribute values.
But considering a scriptlet inside the attribute value which would be calling functions might have parameters with double quotes and that is where the above-mentioned patterns fail.

So for an attribute

```
<div value="<%=AnyText%>"></div>
```

The first pattern would give me `<%=AnyText%>`

But when I use the same pattern for

```
<div value="<%=myFunction.getValue("some Key")%>"></div>
```

the pattern would return `<%=myFunction.getValue(` instead of <%=myFunction.getValue("some Key")%>

How to fix it?

Comment: Which one do you really want - `A method to extract all attributes of a HTML element` Or `Java RegEx pattern to extract all attributes of a HTML element` ?

Comment: Don't use regex to process HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2610466

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, A java pattern to pick the entire attribute.I'll just specify the attribute name in the pattern itself

Comment: @Krypt1, I'm not parsing the processed HTML. I have a JSP file and that is where I am parsing

Comment: There is no such thing as `Java pattern`, you are using `Regular Expressions`. Now, the question is - why do you specifically want to do it with `Regular Expressions` and not something else?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I am talking about java.util.regex.Pattern. It's not regex precisely right ?. Isn't there a small difference and if regex isn't the best option I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It is RegEx. And if you are open for alternatives then use any html parser library. Example - https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Comment: That helps , Thanks @SarveshKumarSingh.